# E4X: Use string as attribute name in expression?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

I have a function that has this line:

```
var returnString:String = items[0].@month;
```

@month is an attibute on an XML node like so:

```
<xmlnode month="JAN"/>
```

OK but I need to abstract the attribute name so I can pass a string to the function and get the contents of the attribute with the name matching the string I passed. So for example If I call the function like this function("stone") it returns items[0].@stone. I hope this is clear.

Does anyone know how to do what I am after?

Thanks.

Comment: Looking a all the comments I cant help but think there is something wrong here.  I tested the solutions that were described by your answers and am not getting the results that you guys are talking about. ~~~~~ So I have some basic xml with an attribute ' id="hey" ' ~~~~~ `trace(xml.@id);` // traces: hey ~~~~~ `trace(xml.@['id']);` // traces blank ~~~~~ `trace(xml.attribute('id'));` // traces blank ~~~~~ also making 'id' into a String (from a literal) doesn't help any.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use attribute('stone') rather than @stone, its the same thing, @stone is just a shorthand way of writing it.

Comment: It worked for the person who originally asked the question as well in several of my applications i was working on at the time the question was posed. Perhaps your problem is slightly different.

Comment: The reason you're running into problems is that you're using a custom namespace. Our answers do not take into account the use of a custom namespace as it was not part of the original question. If you remove the custom namespace from your code, our answers should all work (although I have not tested the others). If you truly wanted help with your problem though, you should of posed your own question instead of maliciously down voting perfectly valid answers. I suggest you read this article to better understand of why your use of a namespace caused your problem: http://adobe.ly/lcSLZS

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as:

```
var attrName:String = "month";
return items[0].@[ attrName ];
```

Answer (score 2):

not only that, but if you ever want to assign a value to an attribute using a variable for the attribute name, you can do this (although it is not documented) like so:

```
  public function setAttr(obj:XML, attrName:String, value:String):void{
     obj.@[attrName] = value;
  }
```